# MSSQL CONCAT query throws Error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I'm tried to execute the below query in MSSQL 2008 R2,but its throwing error.
THE QUERY IS:

```
    SELECT (n_artifactType+(' '+ n_actionPerformed)) AS actionperformed, 
    COUNT(n_actionPerformed) total FROM notifications WHERE   n_project='JupiterQA'
    GROUP BY actionperformed order by n_actionPerformed;
```

ERROR IS:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'actionperformed'.
```

Using 'actionperformed' as alias name even though its throwing error.
How can I execute above query without error.

Comment: please include your table column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it `actionperformed` is an alias name and not an actual table field (or expression of), which is required by a `group by` clause.

Suggest `group by (n_artifactType+(' '+ n_actionPerformed))` instead.

Interestingly `order by` would however be happy with an alias.

Comment: I'm using DATE(n_received) in MYSQL and I need equivalent in MSSQL.

Comment: Sorry not sure i am following

Comment: In MSSQL you could use convert, like this 
`select CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),111);` to convert a `DateTime` to a formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `group by` section of the `query`, group by will not work with alias change it to actual expression i.e.`(n_artifactType+(' '+ n_actionPerformed))`